# Include specific parts of a standalone subfile

Tags: input, exam, include, standalone

I'm trying to compile one main file of exercises where each exercise is a standalone TeX file. `standalone` is the perfect package for that but it lacks the customizability to choose a specific part of the subfile to be added.

In this case, I'm using `documentclass{exam}` which takes individual questions in `\question` and enumerates them. The problem with the `standalone`is when each exercise is a standalone TeX file, combining them assigns each of the exercises in the main file the number 1., they won't enumerate.

My goal main file:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{standalone} %or any suitable package

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
     \input{exercise1}
     \input{exercise2}
     \input{exercise3}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

A sample exercise file:

```
% exercise1.tex
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
   \begin{questions}
      \question A sample question
        \begin{solution}
            Solution Here
        \end{solution}
   \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Since this approach includes `\begin{questions}` field to the main file it does not work. It ends up with two nested `\begin{questions}`

So is there a package to include what's inside a specific tag or environment (`question` env. in my case) or another workaround for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could work:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{standalone} %or any suitable package

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
  \begingroup
     \renewenvironment{questions}{}{}
     \input{exercise1}
     \input{exercise1}
     \input{exercise1}
  \endgroup
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome... Happy TeXing!

Comment: The \renewenvironment and \inputs should all be enclosed in { }. Without this, the outer \end{questions} has no effect and the exam class' "addpoints" option breaks.

Comment: fixed @user1476176 ... Thanks